# evaluating user input for conditions with eval

Tags: python

I need to filter a big list with more then 500,000 items
against search phrases produced from user input.

Init:

```
>>> import glob2
>>> bl = glob2.glob('/foldername/*')
```

Let see:

```
>>> phrase = 'keyword1'
>>> len([x for x in bl if phrase in x])
163
```

correct and fast

```
>>> phrase ='"keyword1" in x'
>>> len([x for x in bl if eval(phrase)])
163
```

correct but very slow

```
>>> phrase ='"keyword1" or "keyword2"'
>>> len([x for x in bl if phrase in x]
0
```

wrong of course

```
>>> phrase ='"keyword1" in x or "keyword2" in x'
>>> len([x for x in bl if eval(phrase)])
205
```

correct but very slow

User given phrases must support many keywords combined with booleans. E.g. "keyword1 or keyword2 not keyword3". A parser that creates valid phrases from simple input lines like "keyword1 keyword2 -keyword3" also would be great. Of course "keyword" is just a placeholder for a large number of different words which each may exist in the bi list several times.

Thanx for reading

[Edit]Leave it!
I've decided to add go the extra mile for another layer with sqlite.

Comment: I'd like to suggest to create a list from `phrase` by dropping all terms with `not` in the front. You can achieve this with a simple regular expression. After you eliminate all unnecessary, you can build a list and perform comparing using lists without eval.

Comment: For what I'm concerned about `phrase = '"key1" in x and not "key2" in x'` works correctly.